# If we remove group by than shot order show correctly but r2table have multiple record

Tags: mysql, sql

If we remove group by than shot order show correctly but r2table have multiple record so how to get unitque r.id in desc format?

```
select r.id, r.title
from rtable r left join  r2table rm on (r.id=rm.rid)
where r.userid = '5'
group by r.id
order by rm.id desc
```

Comment: Why do you even LEFT JOIN r2table, since you don't reference any of its columns?

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: did you already try using DISTINCT?

Comment: can you please share the schema of the 2 tables, some sample data, and the expected result?

Comment: Table 1) post table) post id, post title, post user
Table 2) post message list) mess id, post id, from user id, to user id, message
Each post have multiple user communication
I want to get post title list only that show first those post that have recent message